# Eventually didn't tolerate unsuccessful attempts before giving up

Tags: scala, akka, scalatest

I have a simple test case which is using TestActorRef and eventually to verify a timeout call of a method. Here is details of 3 file sources:

**TestRestUtility.scala**

```scala
import play.api.http.HttpVerbs
import play.api.libs.ws.WSClient

import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.Future

class TestRestUtility @Inject()(ws: WSClient) extends HttpVerbs {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  def getHealthStatus(): Future[Int] = {
    ws.url("https://www.google.com").get().map { response =>
      response.status
    }
  }

}
```

**TestHealthCheckActor.scala**

```scala
import akka.actor.{Actor, ActorLogging, Props}
import play.api.http.Status

import javax.inject.Inject
import scala.concurrent.Future
import scala.concurrent.duration.{DurationInt, FiniteDuration}
import scala.util.{Failure, Success}

object TestHealthCheckActor {
  def props(testRestUtility: TestRestUtility): Props = {
    Props(new TestHealthCheckActor(testRestUtility: TestRestUtility))
  }
}

class TestHealthCheckActor @Inject()(testRestUtility: TestRestUtility)
  extends Actor with ActorLogging with Status {

  import context.dispatcher

  val checkPeriod: FiniteDuration = 1.seconds
  var apiStatus: Int = _

  override def preStart(): Unit = {
    context.system.scheduler.scheduleWithFixedDelay(
      0.milliseconds,
      checkPeriod,
      self,
      RefreshHealthStatus
    )
  }

  override def receive: Receive = {
    case RefreshHealthStatus =>
      val health: Future[Int] = testRestUtility.getHealthStatus()

      health.onComplete({
        case Success(result) =>
          result match {
            case OK => apiStatus = Status.OK
            case _ => apiStatus = Status.REQUEST_TIMEOUT
          }
        case Failure(e) =>
          println(e)
      })
  }
}
```

**TestSpec.scala**

```scala
import akka.actor.{ActorSystem, PoisonPill}
import akka.testkit.{ImplicitSender, TestActorRef, TestKit}
import org.mockito.Mockito
import org.mockito.Mockito.{times, verify, when}
import org.scalatest
import org.scalatest.{BeforeAndAfterAll, BeforeAndAfterEach}
import org.scalatest.concurrent.Eventually
import org.scalatest.matchers.should.Matchers
import org.scalatest.time.Span
import org.scalatest.wordspec.AnyWordSpecLike
import org.scalatestplus.mockito.MockitoSugar
import play.api.http.Status

import scala.concurrent.Future

class TestSpec extends TestKit(ActorSystem("HealthCheckActorSpec")) with AnyWordSpecLike with Matchers
with BeforeAndAfterEach with MockitoSugar with ImplicitSender with Eventually with BeforeAndAfterAll with Status with TestHarnessConstants {

  import scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext.Implicits.global

  var mockTestRestUtility: TestRestUtility = _

  "HealthCheckActor" should {    
    "time out and call subscription api" in {
      mockTestRestUtility = mock[TestRestUtility]
      when(mockTestRestUtility.getHealthStatus()).thenReturn(Future(OK)).thenReturn(Future(OK)).thenReturn(Future(OK))
      val healthCheckActorShortPeriod: TestActorRef[TestHealthCheckActor] = TestActorRef(TestHealthCheckActor.props(mockTestRestUtility))

      eventually(timeout(Span(9, scalatest.time.Seconds)), interval(Span(1, scalatest.time.Seconds))) {
        verify(mockTestRestUtility, Mockito.atLeast(3)).getHealthStatus()
      }

      healthCheckActorShortPeriod ! PoisonPill
    }
  }
}
```

As description about eventually in "scalatest-core_2.12-3.2.3-sources.jar", it tolerates  unsuccessful attempts before giving up, so the test case is expected to have 3 calls the method **getHealthStatus()** to be successful as the returned value from mock. But I got a failed test case with below error message. I don't know why the method was called only one time:

```scala
testRestUtility.getHealthStatus();
Wanted *at least* 3 times:
-> at com.deere.isg.ingest.supporttool.testharness.TestSpec.$anonfun$new$8(TestSpec.scala:44)
But was 1 time:
-> at com.deere.isg.ingest.supporttool.testharness.TestHealthCheckActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(TestHealthCheckActor.scala:36)

org.mockito.exceptions.verification.TooFewActualInvocations: 
testRestUtility.getHealthStatus();
Wanted *at least* 3 times:
-> at com.deere.isg.ingest.supporttool.testharness.TestSpec.$anonfun$new$8(TestSpec.scala:44)
But was 1 time:
-> at com.deere.isg.ingest.supporttool.testharness.TestHealthCheckActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(TestHealthCheckActor.scala:36)
```

Answer (score 0):

`Future(OK)` will be considered successful by `eventually` because it doesn't throw an exception (technically neither would a failed `Future`, unless you unwrapped it in the `eventually`).  Since the first call succeeded, `eventually` won't make any attempts after the first.